# Escaping underscore

Tags: listings, color

I want to colorize a part of text within `lstlisting`. Here is an example:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\linespread{0.8}\footnotesize\ttfamily, language=tcl, escapeinside={<@}{@>}]
  set_param drc.disableLUTOverUtilError 1
} {

      <@\textcolor{red}{              

      red\_text \\

      set\_property PACKAGE\_PIN V20 [get\_ports {red[0]}]

      }@>

\end{lstlisting}
```

`\textcolor` does not allow to use underscore without using `\` in front of it. There are tens of underscores that I want use within `\textcolor` and I don't want to add `\` for each underscore. Is there a way to get rid of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably rather want a *delimiter* than to escape to LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
  basicstyle = \linespread{0.8}\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  language   = tcl,
  moredelim  = [is][\color{red}]{<@}{@>}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle]
set_param drc.disableLUTOverUtilError 1
}{
  <@red_text \\
  set_property PACKAGE_PIN V20 [get_ports {red[0]}] @>
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe something like `moredelim  = [is][\color{red}]{<RED}{RED>}` or `moredelim  = [is][\color{red}]{<EMPH}{EMPH>}` would be a better choice than `{<@}{@>}`…